# How to get data returned by RESTlet from Netsuite accounts that have installed my Bundle (SuiteApp)?

Tags: bundle, netsuite

I could create bundle (SuiteApp) using *RESTlet* file. My uploaded bundle from the repository can be installed by another account. But I don't know how to access the data (such as customers, contacts, etc.) returned by RESTlet from whoever installed my bundle.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, that is a correct approach. Without the consent of target account users you cannot pull their records/data.

You can bundle application tokens, but, user tokens needs to be configured manually in each of the target account, once, you get the user tokens from target account, you can use your RESTlet logic to fetch the record details you want.

Comment: i want to get contacts, customers and etc from the target accounts. Even though I have an administrator account, There is no option to see managed bundle and install base.

Comment: Managed Bundle is available at the time of creating bundles, for an existing non-managed bundle you cannot see it as managed one. Also, you cannot get contacts, customers etc. from target account using bundle view. Do you mean that you want to make call to RESTlet in bundle and get contacts, customers etc. from target account?

Comment: Yes . i want to get contacts and others. if i use restlet , i have to push the RESTlet into other account and i need to get consumer key , secret , script id, deployment id and have to generate token (id & secret) . Too tough process. So i chose bundle to access the data. Is the way correct or should i proceed any other way.?

Comment: Please see my answer I have corrected as per your comments